# Insert Values on Input Variable Array

Tags: mysql, arrays, stored-procedures, input

I have the following input of a list of clients I get from an external application that comes into a variable in a MySQL stored procedure such as this:

```
"2841,2212,1231,xxxx,...,1221"
```

...called input_clients

I want to take this list and insert it all in a temporary table with the field client_id.

I am wondering if someone can either point me to an existing script or show me how I can format this in a stored procedure that input so it will work as

```
INSERT INTO select_Clients(client_id) VALUES (input_client1), (input_client2)
```

because currently input_client stores all those clients in 1 string.

Comment: External application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a prepared statement inside the procedure as string and then execute it:

```
SET @input = '2841,2212,1231,1221';
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS select_Clients;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE select_Clients(client_id INT);

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO select_Clients(client_id) VALUES (', REPLACE(@input, ',', '),('), ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

http://rextester.com/FPDW88636